# Should GUI object be declared in a separate java class to be accessible

Tags: java, swing

I would like to access one variable that is a part of my GUI class. Should I instantiate my GUI class outside of that GUI class? Right now it is instantiated inside of main which I believe makes it inaccessible for me.

So is the best way to access variables in this class to instantiate this object in a different class and in that class create getters and setters for it?

```
public class NormalDistributionUI extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         new NormalDistributionUI().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Should it be like e.g.

```
public class Main {
    static NormalDistributionUI ndUI;

    public NormalDistributionUI getndUI() {
       return ndUI;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ndUI = new NormalDistributionUI();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** a different idea

```
    public class NormalDistributionUI extends JFrame {
        static NormalDistributionUI ndUI;
        public static void main(String args[]) {

             ndUI = new NormalDistributionUI()
             ndUI.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Does that make more sense than creating a separate class?

Comment: If you are commenting on my answer, I am talking about ndUI.

Comment: I have a feeling that neither of your listed options is optimal. Why do you need `ndUI` to be accessible?

Comment: @bradimus ndUi consists of normalDistributiontable which then consists of  table model which I want to update from a different class

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. The second alternative would work as well, assuming that you called the method `setVisible` somewhere else.

The difference between the two of them is that in the second case the GUI object will be named and, hence, accessible afterwards. In the first case, it is anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a whole separate class. The first one is fine. If you want to manipulate the `NormalDistributionUI` object, you can use a local variable.

```
public class NormalDistributionUI extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         NormalDistributionUI ndUI = new NormalDistributionUI();

         ndUI.setSomeProperty(foobar);
         ndUI.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to manipulate NormalDistributionUI object from a different java class